# Displaying images using Php / JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, scroll

I have 1000 Pictures in MYSQL DB i want to arrange them similar in the way of pinterest.com

I came across masonry jquery Script. although the code tell about the usage with a HTML file , I could not find a way to use it with PHP.

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html
```

Using PHP if I Echo all of the images then the page will be really heavy. How could I Integrate Masonry to Fetch images from the MYSQL DB when i reach the bottom scroll, so that the page is light ?

I am a bit confused regarding this, I am not a Php Expert.
Any Help would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <title>Adi</title>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Adi</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr-transitions.js"></script>


</head>

<body>



<div id="container" class="transitions-enabled infinite-scroll clearfix">
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "ID", "Pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DB") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "test " table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test limit 10")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the records of the "TABLENAME" table into $row array and loop through
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {

// Print out the contents of the entry 

//echo "details: ".$row['id'];
echo '<div class="box">';
echo "<img src=\"images/".$row['image']."\" alt=\"name\" />";
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
<p>Hi</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<nav id="page-nav">
  <a href="2.php"></a>
</nav>

<script >


  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box',
        columnWidth: 60
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Page 2. php contains

```
<?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "ID", "Pass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("DB") or die(mysql_error());

    // Retrieve all the data from the "test " table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test limit 5")
    or die(mysql_error());  

    // store the records of the "TABLENAME" table into $row array and loop through
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {

    // Print out the contents of the entry 

    //echo "details: ".$row['id'];
    echo '<div class="box">';
    echo "<img src=\"images/".$row['image']."\" alt=\"name\" />";
    echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Blake - I have updated the code , but i have manually inserted the images . I want that it automatically get the images from the MYSQL database but not so sure how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to show em off really nice look up this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
its very easy to integrate, I've used it myself.

What you would do is this. after you have all of the isotope set up. (itll show you how to) you set up a PHP function on your page like this.

```
<div id="container">
    <?php
        $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `IMAGES` ORDER BY `ID` Limit 20;"; // 20 Image Limit
        $RESULTS = mysql_query($QUERY);
        while($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($RESULTS)) {
            echo '<div class=" Your Main Name For The Isotope Objects "><img src="' . $ROW['URL'] . '" /></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

the while() will keep going through your DB till it reaches its limit giving you 20 divs with pictures in it.

Comment: isotope also has an infinite scroll feature that does what you ask. and its very lightweight.

Comment: @DJ_plus- I read through the link , I am confused how would be use php to load the images.

In the link all images were already coded into the HTML ?
Or How could I Integrate Masonry to Fetch images from the MYSQL DB when i reach the bottom scroll, so that the page is light ?
So should i link all of my 1000 images in the HTML ? and then use the plugin ?

Comment: The issue is that i have to manually create the Php files.

The Script searches for 2.php and then 3.php and then 4.php so on...
I dont want to create these pages manually , i want it to be automatic ?

:)

(update the code above )  
Some how i feel i have to create some type of look...

Comment: the only other thing you could do i try to use jQuery to change your DB selection. say its Limit 20 at first, then use some jQuery to change your $QUERY to Limit 40 and so on, but im not sure how you would do that...

Comment: @DJ_Plus... 

Yeah... I too am Confused

Comment: sorry mate, just fiddle around in isotope and read up on the documentation of it, theres alot there!